# Error when running HHL algorithm in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, hhl-algorithm

I tried to solve a simple system of two simultaneous linear equations in with HHL algorithm in Qiskit. In particular the system is $Ax=b$, where
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1.5 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & 1.5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
b = \begin{pmatrix}
0.9010 \\
-0.4339 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix $A$ is Hermitian, so HHL should cope with it without any problems.

I wrote following code

```
%matplotlib inline
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ
import numpy as np
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
#HHL in Qiskit
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import HHL

matrix_A = np.array([[1.5, 0.5],[0.5, 1.5]])
vector_b = [0.9010, -0.4339]
#x = [0.8184, -0.5747] #expected result

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
#num_q – Number of qubits required for the matrix Operator instance
#num_a – Number of ancillary qubits for Eigenvalues instance

hhlObject = HHL(matrix = matrix_A, vector = vector_b, quantum_instance = backend, num_q = 2, num_a = 1)

res = hhlObject.run(quantum_instance = backend)
print(res)
```

However, this error occured

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-071684a21c97> in <module>
      9 hhlObject = HHL(matrix = matrix_A, vector = vector_b, quantum_instance = backend, num_q = 2, num_a = 1)
     10 
---> 11 res = hhlObject.run(quantum_instance = backend)
     12 print(res)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/quantum_algorithm.py in run(self, quantum_instance, **kwargs)
     68                 self.quantum_instance = quantum_instance
     69 
---> 70         return self._run()
     71 
     72     @abstractmethod

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.py in _run(self)
    399     def _run(self):
    400         if self._quantum_instance.is_statevector:
--> 401             self.construct_circuit(measurement=False)
    402             self._statevector_simulation()
    403         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.py in construct_circuit(self, measurement)
    204 
    205         # InitialState
--> 206         qc += self._init_state.construct_circuit("circuit", q)
    207 
    208         # EigenvalueEstimation (QPE)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'construct_circuit'
```

I also tried to run `construct_circuit` method before `run` method, however, same error was returned.

**Could you please tell me how to set parameters of HHL algorithm to run it correctly?**

Comment: Have you read the corresponding chapter in Qiskit textbook? https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html It may be helpful.

Comment: @tsgeorgios: Thanks for directing me here. It helped. Please feel free to post the comment as an answer to get the bounty. I will provide my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on *tsgeorgios* information about Qiskit manual and the manual content, I created the code below which works as expected.

```
#BASED ON: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html#4.-Qiskit-Implementation
%matplotlib inline
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT
from qiskit.aqua.components.eigs import EigsQPE
from qiskit.aqua.components.reciprocals import LookupRotation
from qiskit.aqua.operators import MatrixOperator
from qiskit.aqua.components.initial_states import Custom
import numpy as np
#Linear equations solvers
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import HHL, NumPyLSsolver #HHL - quantum, NumPyLSolver - classical

def create_eigs(matrix, num_ancillae, num_time_slices, negative_evals):
    ne_qfts = [None, None]
    if negative_evals:
        num_ancillae += 1
        ne_qfts = [QFT(num_ancillae - 1), QFT(num_ancillae - 1).inverse()]
    
    #Construct the eigenvalues estimation using the PhaseEstimationCircuit
    return EigsQPE(MatrixOperator(matrix=matrix),
                   QFT(num_ancillae).inverse(),
                   num_time_slices=num_time_slices,
                   num_ancillae=num_ancillae,
                   expansion_mode='suzuki',
                   expansion_order=2,
                   evo_time=None,
                   negative_evals=negative_evals,
                   ne_qfts=ne_qfts)

def HHLsolver(matrix, vector, backend, no_ancillas, no_time_slices):
    orig_size = len(vector_b)
    #adapt the matrix to have dimension 2^k
    matrix, vector, truncate_powerdim, truncate_hermitian = HHL.matrix_resize(matrix_A, vector_b)

    #find eigenvalues of the matrix wih phase estimation (i.e. calc. exponential of A, apply 
    #phase estimation) to get exp(lamba) and then inverse QFT to get lambdas themselves
    eigs = create_eigs(matrix, no_ancillas, no_time_slices, False)
    #num_q – Number of qubits required for the matrix Operator instance
    #num_a – Number of ancillary qubits for Eigenvalues instance
    num_q, num_a = eigs.get_register_sizes()

    #construct circuit for finding reciprocals of eigenvalues
    reci = LookupRotation(negative_evals=eigs._negative_evals, evo_time=eigs._evo_time)

    #preparing init state for HHL, i.e. the state containing vector b
    init_state = Custom(num_q, state_vector=vector)

    #construct circuit for HHL based on matrix A, vector B and reciprocals of eigenvalues
    algo = HHL(matrix, vector, truncate_powerdim, truncate_hermitian, eigs,
               init_state, reci, num_q, num_a, orig_size)
    
    #solution on quantum computer
    result = algo.run(quantum_instance = backend)
    print("Solution:\t\t", np.round(result['solution'], 5))
    print("Probability:\t\t %f" % result['probability_result'])

    #refence solution - NumPyLSsolver = Numpy LinearSystem algorithm (classical).
    result_ref = NumPyLSsolver(matrix, vector).run()
    print("Classical Solution:\t", np.round(result_ref['solution'], 5))

matrix_A = np.array([[1.5, 0.5],[0.5, 1.5]])
vector_b = [0.9010, -0.4339]
#x = A^(-1)b = [0.78420, -0.55066] #expected result

processor = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

no_ancillas = 3 #number of ancilla qubits
no_time_slices = 50 #number of timeslices in exponential of matrix A (exp(i*A*t))

HHLsolver(matrix_A, vector_b, processor, no_ancillas, no_time_slices)
```

**Acknowledgement:** The code is based on [Qiskit manual on HHL](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html#4.-Qiskit-Implementation).

Comment: nice. thanks for posting the code. +1